# How to use regex pattern \W in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I have a regex pattern for matching special characters

```
ptr = /\W|_/g
```

It's working fine for every special character except `*`

Here is the my testing results

```
ptr = /\W|_/g
ptr.test('vbk_')
true
ptr.test('vbk*')
false
ptr.test("Select * from user")
true
ptr.test("Select * from user")
true
ptr.test("Select * from user")
true
ptr.test('vbk*')
false
```

When I remove global(`g`) from the pattern it seems working fine can anyone suggest me why this happening

Here are my testing results:

```
ptr = /\W|_/
ptr.test('vbk*')
true
ptr.test('vbk')
false
ptr.test('Select * from user')
true
```

Comment: There's no point in using the `g` modifier when you're just using the regexp to test. It's only useful when you're replacing or returning the matches.

Answer (score 3):

You have to reset the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) or reinitialize the regex pattern.

This happens because when using `g` (global), there is a value called `lastIndex` which refers to the last match index. When reusing the same instance of your regex, the search will continue from there.

```
> ptr = /\W|_/g
/\W|_/g
> ptr.test('vbk*')
true
> ptr.lastIndex
4
> ptr.lastIndex = 0
0
> ptr.test('vbk*')
true
```

The other way is to have a function that returns the regex value:

```
> ptr = () => /\W|_/g
[Function: ptr]
> ptr().test("vbk*")
true
> ptr().test("vbk*")
true
> ptr().test("vbk*")
true
> ptr().test("vbk*")
true
```

The `lastIndex` is useful if you need to start the search from a specific index, otherwise, if you do not need that, simply do not use the `g`lobal flag.

Comment: I got clarification on it, I was not familiar with Lastindex
Thanks, Ionica

Comment: @JitendraYadav Don't forget to mark the answer as correct when you are happy with it. Or if you have any questions, let me know.